# shutting down the google cloud account and project totally, how to save VMs apps and Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google, cloud-computing, google-kubernetes-engine

We have an order to shutdown google Cloud enterprise account now. We were running more than 50 VMs and apps, now the question is how to get these backup'ed and presrve it for future use or may be possible to go with new cloud provider in the *emphasized text*future.
Or we can revive Google project again based on company funds, 
Please advise the best way to safeguard these services/VM/apps. 
P.S -Snapshot is chargeable and backups on cloud storage too per our understanding hence we have to keep our google account active which is not the case here.

Regards,
AMIT LAL

Answer (score 1):

The best answer requires an exact list of services. Most services do not support any form of automated export. You will need to create your own documentation sets.

Once you close your account, you will have 30 days before everything is deleted for most services. Some services such as Stackdriver start purging the day you close your account.

Here are tips for the most common services.

Compute Engine

You can export images of Compute Engine VM instances in several image formats (VMDK, VHDX, etc) to Google Cloud Storage. You can then download these images.

```
gcloud compute images export ...
```

Google Container Registry

You can use the docker command to import a container image to your local repository

```
docker pull ....
```

Google Cloud Functions

The Google Cloud Console has a download zip button to download the source files.

App Engine Standard

You can use the `appcfg.py download_app` command to download your app.

Cloud Storage

Use `gsutil` to download each bucket to local storage.